# How can I make a client server show updated data without send request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, websocket, real-time, django-channels

I design a application for a restaurant one of the features  is that the user can make an order online and the oreder status is pending until the restaurant cashier or restaurant admin staff convert status by accept or refuse
so i wanna send to client  a notification if there is pending orders or something that the admin staff or cashier know that there is an pending order created now without need to update or refresh the client page

so my question is how i make a backend server send to client browser notification without the client need to refresh the page or send request to backend server

- i use django rest framework
- I hear about websocket and Django channels
- Also i hear about SSE
- Also i read about client freamwork send requests every n minute to update the page

I need to know what the best approach to implement this and if there is another technology and what is best for server if there is a lot of loading or the application used by millions of users

Answer (score 0):

For example - you can implementig full-state service on nodejs + express + socket.io or asp.net + signalR. Client connecting to your service via websocket if customer open page where there order status. This solution will allow scale only service if connecting many client, also you should think over communication between service and general app on django, for example use rabbit or kafka or other. Also your can use this service for new realtime features

Comment: Can you tell me some details how can i use kafka with django channels if that possible

Comment: Sorry, i am have not experience on django, but your can look pip package kafka-python